# Сколько одновременно файлов может грузить URLLoader, Loader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Вот какой вопрос - создал я сотню экземпляров загрузчика, сколько из них будут работать-грузить одновременно-синхронно? Вопрос в основном касается работы в браузере, но был бы рад, если бы и про air узнал ( хотя до air я ещё не добрался и не знаю, есть ли отличия в загрузке ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одновременно будут работать столько сколько вы запустите на загрузку (load()). Если 100, значит будет создано 100 соединений к серверу. LoaderMax например сам регулирует кол-во подключений в maxConnections.

Технически эти классы работают одинаково для AIR и для веб проигрывателя. Разница только в песочнице безопасности и путях. Например url - "image.png" будет загружен с текущего сервера для веб приложения, и с диска в папке AIR приложения (iOS/Android/Win/MacOSX).

Comment: @ShockWave: и вот тут ещё вопросы - предположим создалось сто соединений с сервером и это означает, что все сто экземпляров загрузчиков, одновременно начнуть грузить сто файлов? И ещё вопрос - я знаю, что один файл в 10МБ загрузится быстрей чем 10 файлов по 1МБ, а есть ли разница в скорости между ОДНОВРЕМЕННОЙ загрузкой 10 файлов или загрузкой тех же 10 файлов, но по очереди? Спасибо!

Comment: - да, одновременно, хотя если устройство слабое, то может и с задержкой, причем проблемы можно получить уже на 30-и соединениях, лучше не рисковать и держать на уровне 10-20

- разница конечно будет, причем на быстром канале и устройстве, соответственно 10-и кратный прирост и будет наблюдаться

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что! Обращайтесь!